# How to set Application Interactive to false in Office JS?

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to block users from further editing cell before the previous edit completes. I want to make sure previous edit event completes until then interactivity from user should be blocked.I know Excel VBA has this functionality `Application.Interactive = False`. How to achieve this in Office Js?

Answer (score 1):

I saw this functionality is under office dev team's backlog.

**JS API function to prevent user from sheet interaction :**
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/31752895-js-api-function-to-prevent-user-from-sheet-interac

I believe this functionality will be available in future version of Office JS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this scenario is currently supported in Office JS (i.e., there is no Office JS equivalent to VBA's `Application.Interactive` property, as far as I know).